# Is it OK for a journal which already rejected my paper to ask me later on to serve as a reviewer?

Tags: publications, peer-review, rejection

One of my paper was rejected from some journal around one an half year ago (*I still working on my paper, anyway :)*) and during the submission process, I have filled my profile in their submission system and **also ticked the box: available as reviewer**, recently the editor of that journal sent me an invitation to review some paper related to my background. I accepted that invitation and reviewed the paper, and still receiving more invitations from them. **I am really wondering, if I am not qualified to publish with that journal, how I become qualified to review for them ?!!**

Comment: Being qualified to review for them is a much broader activity than having written and submitted **one paper** that does not meet their standards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [I got a paper to review from a journal that had rejected my earlier works, how to respond?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/80341/7734)

Comment: If you don't want to be a reviewer, can you not uncheck the box in their on-line form?

Answer (score 10):

The journal rejected your submitted paper, not you.

The journal asked for you to review a paper for them, not for your submitted paper to review a paper for them.

Journals sometimes use people as reviewers who publish with them, but that's for convenience (they have your contact info and area of interest on file) and to utilize a bit of social capital (asking for a review is a bit of a favor, and people may feel more socially compelled to accept the assignment if a journal has published their papers). It's not like publishing a paper enters you into an exclusive club qualified to review; peer reviewers simply need to be sufficiently expert in their field to offer a professional opinion on a paper.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's fine.

When the publication passed on publishing your work, they were rejecting the project you were currently working on; they were not rejecting you as a researcher or a person. They could have rejected that project for many reasons: maybe there was an issue you still needed to work out with the project, or maybe it wasn't a best fit for the publication. Maybe the editor liked your work but had to respect their reviewers. None of that is a rejection of you: any fair reviewer or editor would understand that what they write doesn't always work with the first journal they submit to. Also, peer reviewers usually don't know who you are.

So I wouldn't connect the decision to pass on your publication with the decision to make you a reviewer.